# Is "type" a reserved word in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

in **notepad++** *SQL language* it highlights the word "**type**" in a blue color but in *mysql* reserved word list/table* I can't find "**type**" in that

If "**type**" is not a reserved word in **mysql** should I avoid the word "**type**" and which alternative word should I use.

Comment: Use something descriptive. `type` is like `id`. It really only goes so far. Tell me more about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Definitely, NO.

- [MySQL Reserved Keywords List](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

When I open my Notepad++, I can't seem to find language for `MySQL`, only `SQL` is available. So the reason why it is highlighted as blue is because it may be reserved keyword from the other languages.

Comment: It is a MySQL keyword, but it is not a reserved word.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Broken - An example of why links are bad. But this list is way too large.  Hence new link is https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html#keywords-5-7-detailed-M

Answer (score 1):

`TYPE` is not a SQL command.

However, I would avoid it for 2 reasons:

- "datatype" is referred to several times in SQL documentation (assuming this means string, int, float.
- `type()` will be a reserved word in many programming languages that you want to use in cooperating with a SQL datastore. Especially if you plan to use that programming language as an ORM.

Answer (score -3):

"type" and "types" are reserved keywords based on [this link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html).

Comment: Hi there, this answer is great, but you should try to expand on short answers that contain links, the following meta post has some great info: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: Based on that link, "type" and "types" are keywords, but they do not have an (R) beside them, so they are not reserved keywords.

Comment: I don't know but is this site they say it's a reserved word: https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words